# Do we need to manually activate windows in GCE VM?

Tags: google-compute-engine, activation

I created a windows VM in GCE from the public image, and I found that the windows is not activated.
Do we need to activate this kind of "on demand" windows license?

Comment: Windows must be activated, in the cloud or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to activate the permium images. It gets charged on our usage.

In GCP, All Windows Server instances must be able to communicate with **kms.windows.googlecloud.com** (35.190.247.13/32) to [activate its license](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows#licensing).

- Check your *VPC network* to allow access to the activation server
  before you create your Windows instance.
- If you have Windows instances without external IP addresses, you must
  enable *Private Google Access*

.

Comment: I am able to ping to kms.windows.googlecloud.com (35.190.247.13/32) but when I test the connection to port 1688, it failed, seem like the port is not opened.

C:\>powershell.exe Test-NetConnection 35.190.247.13 -Port 1688
WARNING: TCP connect to (35.190.247.13 : 1688) failed

ComputerName           : 35.190.247.13
RemoteAddress          : 35.190.247.13
RemotePort             : 1688
InterfaceAlias         : WiFi
SourceAddress          : 192.168.0.173
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 10 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False